# Определение битрейта за данными

Tags: видео, битовые-операции, кодек

Определить битрейт (Мбит/с) канала передачи данных, необходимый для просмотра видео онлайн (без задержек).

- Ширина кадров W: 600.
- Высота кадров H: 450.
- Частота кадров f: 24.
- Глубина цвета C: 24.
- Формат аудио A: 2 канала.
- Частота дискретизации F*, кГц: 44.
- Разрядность аудиоданных D: 24.

Как можно определить?

Comment: Все зависит от того, каким кодеком будет кодироваться видео. В кaw-формате-то ни один нормальный человек передавать не будет.

Comment: Ну raw как раз нужно, то есть это чисто "виртуально"

Comment: А, ну тогда прямо так и посчитайте. На каждый кадр надо 600*450*24 бит. Таких кадров в секунду надо передать 24. Т.е. 600*450*24*24 = 155520000. Аналогично посчитать для аудио, сложить, и перевести в мегабиты.